# How to make sure a "require()" statement is going to be at the top of the transpiled file using babel?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, module-alias

I've got this `index.ts` file I'm transpiling to `index.js` with **babel**.

And I need a specific require to be at the top of the file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

You can see from the `module-alias` doc that that line should be called one time at the main file, before any other code.

[image]

**index.ts**

```
require("module-alias/register");     // <--- THIS LINE NEEDS TO COME BEFORE ANY CODE

// REST OF THE FILE
```

But **babel** is adding a bunch of stuff before that line in the transpiled version.

**index.js**

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true});

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { ... }

function _getRequireWildcardCache() { ... }

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { ... }

// SOME OTHER STUFF

require("module-alias/register");   // THE LINE HAS MOVED DOWN TO HERE
```

Is there a config or some workaround I can do to make sure that line stays on top of the result file?

That line is not working in that position. It really needs to be on top. When I manually move it to the top, everything works fine.